# How to display an image in a Visual C++ application?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

I am trying to display a PNG image in a Visual C++ (2019) application. Its a Win32 dialog based application (I don't use MFC) to show a directory of addresses that contains name, address and a photograph (800x600px). So, all is well except the **Photograph**. I tried all I knew with the help from Internet but still I could not get it to work. An e.g. of how my app looks like is given below.

[image]

What I have tried so far...
(1) Added Images as resources (*You can see images in the "Resource Files"*).
(2) Created the Dialog Box where the image would be displayed.
(3) Added a **Picture Control** to the dialog box.
(4) Tried to connect the Image to the **Picture Control**... (~Problem~)

So, I still did not find a way to connect "Picture Control" to the "Image". Appreciate it if you could show me how to do it, or send me a link where it describes the way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/gdiplusheaders/nf-gdiplusheaders-bitmap-bitmap(constwchar_bool) takes any image file and creates a bitmap out of it (easier to manipulate in program).

```
#include <gdiplusheaders.h>

Bitmap bmp = Bitmap(L"c:\\users\\user\\restofpath\\image.png"); //Get bitmap
HBITMAP hBitmap;
bmp.GetHBITMAP(0, &hBitmap); //Make it an HBITMAP
HDC hdc = GetDC(hwnd); //Get HDC from window handle (can be any window)
HIMAGELIST imageList = ImageList_Create(640, 480, ILC_COLOR24, 1, 10); //Create image list with images of 640 (width) * 480 (height) and 24 bits rgb
ImageList_Add(imageList, hBitmap, NULL); //Add the bitmap to the imageList
BOOL drawn = ImageList_Draw(imageList, 0, hdc, 0, 0, ILD_IMAGE); //Draw the image on the window
DeleteObject(hBitmap);
ImageList_Destroy(imageList);
DeleteObject(hdc);
```

You can look at ImageList_Create function for other options: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/nf-commctrl-imagelist_create. Especially the flags section which allows to personalize the type of image to draw. If you want to maintain PNG transparency you might want to use 32 bits DIB.

Comment: You don\t need an image list to render an image. Since you've already gone for GDI+ you can simply call [Graphics::DrawImage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/gdiplusgraphics/nf-gdiplusgraphics-graphics-drawimage(image_constpoint_)). Also note that GDI+ requires [initialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/gdiplusinit/).

Comment: Easier yet, since there's already a Picture Control, send it an [STM_SETIMAGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/stm-setimage) message and not have to deal with rendering at all.